# How can I reliably determine if a browser supports the DataTransfer() constructor?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, data-transfer

I have a file uploader that uses `new DataTransfer()` to generate and display thumbnails for uploaded images. For Safari users, this constructor is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/DataTransfer). The tricky part is that `DataTransfer` as a feature *is* supported - it's specifically the constructor that is not.

How can I detect if this feature exists, so that I can provide a standard `file` input for Safari users? To clarify, I'm not looking for help with the fallback - just the feature detection itself.

I attempted the following to no avail:

```
const isConstructor = (func) => (func && typeof func === "function" && func.prototype && func.prototype.constructor) === func;

isConstructor(DataTransfer);  //true in Safari
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this, but in a somewhat hacky fashion that I'm not quite happy with. I'll still take any better answers I can get.

```js
let dataTransferConstructorSupported = false;
try { new DataTransfer(), dataTransferConstructorSupported = true } catch {}

console.log(dataTransferConstructorSupported);
```